# Go to another drive with same path using Far Manager's user menu

Tags: batch-file, far-manager

On one of my PCs has two hard drives with identical directories structure.

I would like to have in Far Manager an user menu item to go quickly to the same path, but on another drive. For example, if the current directory is `"D:\Storage\Backups"`, it should switch to `"E:\Storage\Backups"`.

Following user menu script

```
@set mystring="!\"
@set mmstr=%mystring:d:\=e:\%
@echo %mmstr%
```

results in outputting

> %mystring:d:\=e:\%

But when I change `set` to `echo`

```
@set mystring="!\"
@echo %mystring:d:\=e:\%
```

it returns the correct string:

> "e:\Storage\Backups"

If I replace `echo` with `cd`

```
@set mystring="!\"
@cd %mystring:d:\=e:\%
```

it doesn't work, because it tries to change to `%mystring:d:\=e:\%` instead of `E:\Storage\Backups`.

How to set environment variable with string replace in Far Manager's script?